# I need to create a multiple options selections page in which each selections adds or substracts the price of a product

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am getting new into programming languages, I already know  HTML and CSS and I am starting with Javascript and PHP. I am a very beginner, so please be patient with me!

I wanted to ask you the following:

I have a page where you have got different options to select, and I wanted each of this option add (or substract) value of the product´s price.

What I have right now is different radio inputs.
I copy and paste my code:

```
                <li class="250W" >
                    <input type="radio" name="motorpower" id="power1"   class="motorpowerinput"/>
                    <label for="power1" class="powerlabel">Brushless DC Motor rated at 250W<br /> </label> 

                </li>

                 <li class="350W">
                    <input type="radio" name="motorpower" id="power2" class="motorpowerinput"/>
                    <label for="power2" class="powerlabel">Brushless DC Motor rated at 350W</label>

                </li>

                 <li class="500W">
                    <input type="radio" name="motorpower" id="power3" class="motorpowerinput"/>
                    <label for="power3" class="powerlabel">Brushless DC Motor rated at 500W</label>

                </li>

                <li class="750W">
                    <input type="radio" name="motorpower" id="power4" class="motorpowerinput"/>
                    <label for="power4" class="powerlabel">Brushless DC Motor rated at 750W</label>

                </li>

                <li class="1000W">
                    <input type="radio" name="motorpower" id="power5" class="motorpowerinput"/>
                    <label for="power5" class="powerlabel">Brushless DC Motor rated at 1000W</label>

                </li>

                </ul>
```

I created a variable var1 which is displayed on a fixed header, and I wanted that, if I selected for example the 350W input it added, for example, the value 100 to the variable. I tried the following:

```
if(document.getElementById('power1').checked) {
var1 + 100;}
```

and also

```
if ('input[id=power1]:checked') {
var1 + 100;}
```

but none of them has worked for me.

Could you offer me a solution? And also, if you think it is better to use PHP for that, I'm open for any solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The first very important thing to understand is that javascript and HTML don't keep watching your webpage state all the time. They only do this when you open the page.

If you want to execute some script after page loading, you have to trigger it. This can be done with for example the "onclick" parameter in HTML. Take your code:

```
  ...

   <li class="350W">
        <input type="radio" name="motorpower" id="power2" class="motorpowerinput"/>
        <label for="power2" class="powerlabel">Brushless DC Motor rated at 350W</label>
   </li>

  ...
```

You can make this interactive by changing it into:

```
  ...

   <li class="350W">
        <input type="radio" name="motorpower" id="power2" class="motorpowerinput" onclick="<your javascript here>"/>
        <label for="power2" class="powerlabel">Brushless DC Motor rated at 350W</label>
   </li>

  ...
```

It is also important to note a difference between Javascript and PHP. Javascript will all be executed within your browser and is called "client-side". PHP is executed on a server, most of the times running on a remote computer, called "server-side".

In practice these forms you now use often send a request to a server with the use of a "submit" button ([more on that over here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)). In general sense you could say you would use Javascript to whether inputs are written the way you want (if a phone no. contains 10 digits for example) and PHP for handling the request (storing the data in a database).

Comment: But I tried and I don't get it added to my variable. I have got a variable at the beginnig called var1, then, in my code it says: <input (......) onclick="priceadd">                                                                                             <script> function priceadd(){ var1 + 100; document.write(var1);     and the initial value continues!

Comment: What is the HTML code around the variable you are talking about? Javascript has something that is called a "scope", which shields off variables used in functions. If you use the name "var1" in the onclick action, it will see it as just some value that doesn't do anything. You want to link to your specific "var1" in the top of the screen. Do that for example by using "document.getElementById("<your id>")" if you gave your variable an id. To understand what you're doing, take a quick look at [this article on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp)

Comment: And you might want to [look at this example](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_html.asp) for changing a value on your page with javascript.